# Deleting rows in pandas unitil the specific value first occurred

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to delete the rows that users equal to 1 first occurred and its previous rows for each unique user in the DataFrame.

For instance, I have the following Dataframe, and I would like to get another dataframe which deletes the row in the "val" column 1 first occured and its previous rows for each user.

```
      user  val
0      1    0
1      1    1
2      1    0
3      1    1
4      2    0
5      2    0
6      2    1
7      2    0
8      3    1
9      3    0
10     3    0
11     3    0
12     3    1
```

---

```
     user  val 
0      1    0 
1      1    1
2      2    0 
3      3    0 
4      3    0 
5      3    0 
6      3    1
```

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd 

s = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
t = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(s,t), columns=['user', 'val'])
```

Comment: Don't include images in the post. It's far better to have easily visible code. I also simplified the DataFrame creation.

Comment: I don't understand your rule, can you put clarify it? or indicate which row in the original dataframe will be deleted & why

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` checking `cummax` and `shift` to remove all rows before, and including, the first `1` in the `'val'` column per user.

Assuming your values are either 1 or 0, also possible to create the mask with a double cumsum.

```
m = df.groupby('user').val.apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).cummax().shift().fillna(False))
# m = df.groupby('user').val.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().cumsum().gt(1)) 
df.loc[m]
```

#### Output:

```
    user  val
2      1    0
3      1    1
7      2    0
9      3    0
10     3    0
11     3    0
12     3    1
```